# Creating directories in OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift

I think this has something to do with my SSH keys, but I'm not quite sure.

I can log into my app through terminal using:

```
rhc ssh getYahooPrices
```

However, when I try to make a new directory with:

```
mkdir data
```

I get this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `data': Permission denied
```

How can my permission be denied if I'm already in the app?

I've also tried:

```
sudo mkdir data
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have root permissions on your gear. In particular on specific directories are writable by you. Do an `ls -la` and you see the different permissions for all the folders. You can create directories in the folders which are owned by the app, however, some of of them might get deleted and re-created on deploys. See also https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398490-Persistant-storage-for-OpenShift-applications. There is already a data dir under `app-root`. You probably should use that one.